# How supply an outdoor string light with 10 LED bulbs 0.8W?

Tags: arduino, led, resistors, light, string

I currently have a outdoor string light with 10 LED bulbs 0.8W powered by a 3.7V lithium battery and recharged by a solar panel (5.5V 295mA).
Over time the battery discharges and no longer works. I've changed it 3 times in two years.

I'd like to connect my string light to an ESP32 NODEMCU and do without the solar panel. I've also noticed a voltage of 10.4V on the bulbs.

To do this, I was thinking of connecting a GPIO in place of the battery, with a minimum resistance of 82.5 ohms (as the maximum current supplied by the GPIO is 40mA). But I have the impression that the bulbs will run out of power.

I know that the LEDs have a total power of 8W and I want to connect them directly. If I use a 5V voltage or a 12V voltage, how do I determine which resistor to put in series if I don't know the current?

Is my logic correct?
For a 5V voltage, the resistor must be at least :
P = V * I
I = P / V = 8 / 5 = 1.6 A
V = R * I
R = V / I = 5 / 1.6 = 3.125 ohm
In this configuration, I'd like to use a Breadboard Power Supply Module, but the maximum current is 700mA.

For a voltage of 12V, the resistance must be at least :
P = V * I
I = P / V = 8 / 12 = 0.67 A
V = R * I
R = V / I = 12 / 0.67 = 18 ohm

Is there an easier way to power this string light?
How does a 3.7 V battery manage to power this string light, perhaps because it doesn't work at full power after all?

Thank you for your help in enlightening me and sorry for the long message.

---

[image: Solar panel charger 1]
[image]

Here is the electronic card
T+ comes from the Solar panel
A+ goes to the battery
L (bottom) goes to the bulbs

Comment: Show us a picture of the inside of the device and how it's hooked up.

Comment: ESP32 NODEMCU is not suitable as a power supply ... use it for control only

Comment: If you measured 10.4 v out from 3.7v in then the device includes a circuit to step up the voltage to 10.4v. if that is true then you cannot use a 5v supply and a resistor.

Comment: Thom - Hi, You wrote an "answer" but it was actually more info, not a solution, so it has been added to your question as an edit (i.e. an update) instead. || Since you asked the question, then unless you are writing the *full & final* answer to your own question (i.e. unless you don't need further help & you have solved the problem yourself using a different solution than any other answer) please *don't* use the box labeled "Your Answer" below. Instead, to add clarification or more info, please [edit] the question (unless that would invalidate an answer). || Please see the [tour] & [help].

Comment: Look up how to use a transistor to turn something on and off.

Comment: Your question is inconsistent, saying both "0.8W" and "8W". Which is it? Thx.

Answer (score 2):

My experience with inexpensive solar-powered night lights is that the photovoltaic array *and* the battery are too small to power the light through a whole night. This invariably leads to cycling the battery too deeply, too often, destroying it.

However, I've found a few work-arounds:

- Add a second solar panel from a defunct light in parallel with the existing one,
- Also use a larger battery. For example, one light came with size 18650 cell, but rated at *only 500 mA-h*. Replacing with a better cell gave about three times the run-time.
- Adding a series resistor somewhat reduces brightness, but greatly extends run time. The eye's sensitivity to light is *roughly* logarithmic, so cutting power to a quarter reduces perceived brightness to half.